# characterizing the sup over distributions in terms of quantile functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions, supremum-and-infimum

For family of distributions $\mathcal{D}$, random variable $X$, its distribution function $F \in \mathcal{D}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\epsilon \in [0,1]$, I'm trying to characterize:
$$
\begin{align}
\sup_{F\in\mathcal{D}} \{\mathbb{P}_F(X < c)\} := \sup_{F\in\mathcal{D}} \{F(c)\} &\leq \epsilon
\end{align}
$$
in terms of $X$'s quantile function $F^{-}(u) := \inf \{x: F(x) \geq u\}$. I have referenced [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210683/proof-that-quantile-function-characterizes-probability-distribution!) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7282/does-the-quantile-function-uniquely-determine-the-distribution-function!) but am not sure how to use them.

What I want to do is say something like:
$$
\begin{align}
\sup_{F\in\mathcal{D}} \{ F(c) \} &\leq \epsilon \iff c \leq \inf_{F\in\mathcal{D}} \{ F^{-}(\epsilon) \}
\end{align}
$$
but I'm not sure if this is an equivalent characterization. Is this the right way to relate $\sup$ and $\inf$ with an inequality?  Am I implicitly assuming some nice properties (continuity or monotonicity, maybe) about $F$?

Comment: I am not familiar with all these, but I guess yes - you may need the strictly increasing stuff. If $F$ is allow to be constant over an interval, without increasing, then there may have some point $c_0 < c$ such that $F(c_0) = F(c) = e$. And I suppose your quantile function will take the infimum.

Comment: @BGM: Thanks, so if I suppose the strictly increasing stuff, is this characterization ok?